# How to set up C++ REST SDK on VS 2015

Tags: c++, rest

So i'm new to libraries and learning to design API's.. I need this library to create a program that checks if a username already exist using an API provided by site. Anyway, i already installed the ZIP File v2.7.0 on Github

> https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/tree/v2.7.0

I read the documentation but it's too hard to understand.. For me it's not a noob friendly.. But i choose the "Build from source" What i did so far is open the cpprestsdk140.sln and build it using VS 2015. What's next after it? Is it installed already ? How will i use this for the program i want to accomplish?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: If you want to learn how to work with a HTTP RESTful API, I would suggest you to look at some web framework first (like NodeJS, or some PHP framework). If you're not familiar with C++, it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: While you *can* build it yourself, it's a lot easier to install a precompiled package via NuGet. In your solution, go to Project -> Manage NuGet Packages..., and under `Browse` search for "cpprestsdk". Once you have installed that, it's ready to go - you can include everything from `<cpprest/...>`, the libraries will be linked automatically, and the DLLs deployed to your output directory alongside your executable.

Comment: Which solution? The cpprestsdk140.sln ?

Comment: Anyway it doesn't work i did your step on sample console application..

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You install the "cpprestsdk" nuget package into *your project*, maybe reload your the solution. Then everything worked for me.

Comment: @melak47 I think you should post that as an answer.